# sfdx force:source:pull doesn't retrieve FlowVisibilityRule

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, visibility

I created a Flow with several conditional rendering of screen components. When I pull the source from the scratch org, the metadata of the flow is missing the FlowVisibilityRule for all the components, so this functionality is missing.

Do I have to set something specific to pull these information or is there any other workaround (besides creating those metadata manually)?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, when I set the API version to 47.0 and rebuild it in a newly created scratch org, the visibility rules for the screen components have been pulled.

This is confirmed by looking at the [Metadata API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) for Flow and FlowVisibilityRule

[image]

Comment: Having same issue. I logged in using workbench with Api version set to 48.0.
I retrieved the flows but FlowVisibilityRule is not set. Any Idea, help plz